# Requests done in the onModuleLoad are not cached at all. Mainly in FireFox

Tags: http, firefox, gwt, firebug

I faced an issue in which requests that are done in the onModuleLoad event are not being cached in most cases (mainly with FireFox). I checked the network console on FireBug and it almost always shows those kinds of requests being fetched from the server and not from the cache.

I prepared a test case, you can check it at http://tradeosam.appspot.com/

and here is the onModuleLoad implementation:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,
            "query/test?v=1-8951245");
    try {
        request.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                    Response response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
    }

    new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,
                    "query/test?v=1-23478.34");
            try {
                request.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                            Response response) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                    }
                });
            } catch (RequestException e) {
            }
        }
    }.schedule(1000);
}
```

As you can see from the code, I do two requests onModuleLoad, the first one is directly done and is almost never being cached by the browser. The second one is done with a timer after 1 second, and is cached with no problems.
Both these requests have the same headers, and go to the same Servlet, the only difference is the "v" parameter which is used to differentiate between the two.

Comment: I cannot open your test case. :O

Comment: Before Timer, make two calls. What happens? Is one of them cached?

Comment: @qben I updated my test case, and added another call before the timer, and as I saw from Firebug both requests are still not cached

Comment: I still cannot open your test case. I get `Check your network console for requests behavior. Better to try with FireFox`. Tried in Firefox 18.0.2 and in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear, but this is my test case, it is just an empty page and the requests are done once you load it. Just open firebug when you load it and you will see the requests

Comment: I don't know what is the answer but your question seems to be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't see "query/test" requests in your showcase, but all XHR requests that I see there don't have any caching instructions for browser. By default browsers do not cache XHR requests, b/c as a rule such requests must bring most fresh data. But if you want to force browser caching them, just add Cache-Control into request header on client side. I cannot specify concrete rules, because I don't know your requirements for it - at least how long it should keep data.

Please refer to RFC: "[Caching in HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)" and to fine article about http caching: "[Caching Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)".

Hope this helps.